# An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am teaching myself Spring by dissecting example applications and then adding code here and there to test theories that I develop during the dissection.  I am getting the following error message when testing some code that I added to a Spring application:

```
An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the  
model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments to which they apply
```

The method to which the error message refers is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/catowners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findOwnersOfPetType(Integer typeID, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {
    // find owners of a specific type of pet
    typeID = 1;//this is just a placeholder
    Collection<Owner> results = this.clinicService.findOwnerByPetType(typeID);
    model.put("selections", results);
    return "owners/catowners";
}
```

This error message was triggered when I tried to load the /catowners url pattern in the web browser. I have reviewed [this page](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) and [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449532/spring-mvc-3-1-exception-an-errors-bindingresult-argument-is-expected-to-be-im), but the explanation does not seem clear.

Can anyone show me how to fix this error, and also explain what it means?

EDIT:
Based on Biju Kunjummen's response, I changed the syntax to the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/catowners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findOwnersOfPetType(@Valid Integer typeID, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model)
```

I am still getting the same error message.  Is ther something I am not understanding?

SECOND EDIT:

Based on Sotirios's comment, I changed the code to the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/catowners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findOwnersOfPetType(BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {
    // find owners of a specific type of pet
    Integer typeID = 1;//this is just a placeholder
    Collection<Owner> results = this.clinicService.findOwnerByPetType(typeID);
    model.put("selections", results);
    return "owners/catowners";
 }
```

I am still getting the same error message after telling eclipse to run as...run on server again.

Is there something that I am not understanding?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Spring uses an interface called `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to resolve the parameter in your handler methods and construct an object to pass as an argument.

If it doesn't find one, it passes `null` (I have to verify this).

The `BindingResult` is a result object that holds errors that may have come up validating a `@ModelAttribute`, `@Valid`, `@RequestBody` or `@RequestPart`, so you can only use it with parameters that are annotated as such. There are `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` for each of those annotations.

**EDIT (response to comment)**

Your example seems to show that the user should provide a pet type (as an integer). I would change the method to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/catowners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findOwnersOfPetType(@RequestParam("type") Integer typeID, Map<String, Object> model)
```

And you would make your request (depending on your config) as

```
localhost:8080/yourcontext/catowners?type=1
```

Here too there is nothing to validate so you don't want or need a `BindingResult`. It would fail if you tried to add it anyway.

Answer (score 10):

If you have a parameter of type `BindingResult` it is essentially to hold any errors when binding http request parameters to a variable declared directly preceding the BindingResult method parameter.

So all of these is acceptable:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/catowners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findOwnersOfPetType(@Valid MyType type, BindingResult result, ...)


@RequestMapping(value = "/catowners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findOwnersOfPetType(@ModelAttribute MyType type, BindingResult result, ...)

@RequestMapping(value = "/catowners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findOwnersOfPetType(@RequestBody @Valid MyType type, BindingResult result, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a thoughtful answer.  I made an edit to my original posting above using what I thought you were suggesting, but it is still throwing an error message.  Is there something I am not understanding?

Comment: `@Valid` with a integer field will not work. Try to use a containing type instead with a integer field within it followed by the `BindingResult` parameter.