# Spring Controller fetch query parameter for a wrapper request class

Tags: spring, controller

I am trying to build RESTful web service by using spring 4.0

I have a controller:

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("test")  
    public class Controller{
          @RequestMapping("fetch",method=RequestMethod.GET)
          @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
          @ResponseBody
          public ResultResponse fetchController(ResultRequest req){
                 if((req.getName).equals("John"))
                     return new ResultResponse(100);
                  else
                     return new ResultResponse(0);
          }
    }
```

and my ResultRequest.class

```
    public class ResultRequest{
         private String name;
            //getter,setter
    }
```

If I hit the url to //host//contextPath/test/fetch?name=John

the controller will return the object ResultResponse(100)

my question is, there no @RequestParam or other annotation in the request parameter,
how does the spring controller know to set the query parameter "name" as the property of wrapper class
ResultRequest ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring uses implementations of an interface called [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) for resolving arguments to pass to handler methods, ie. methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`.

One of these is a [`ModelAttributeMethodProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.html). Its javadoc states

> **Resolves method arguments annotated with `@ModelAttribute`** and handles
>   return values from methods annotated with `@ModelAttribute`.
>
> Model attributes are obtained from the model or if not found possibly
>   created with a default constructor if it is available. **Once created,
>   the attributed is populated with request data via data binding** and
>   also validation may be applied if the argument is annotated with
>   `@javax.validation.Valid`.
>
> **When this handler is created with `annotationNotRequired=true`, any
>   non-simple type argument and return value is regarded as a model
>   attribute with or without the presence of an `@ModelAttribute`.**

Spring registers two objects of this type. One to handle parameters annotated with `@ModelAttribute` and one to handle ones without.

Further reading:

- [Form submit in Spring MVC 3 - explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944627/form-submit-in-spring-mvc-3-explanation/18944736#18944736)
- [An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646121/an-errors-bindingresult-argument-is-expected-to-be-declared-immediately-after-th/18646314#18646314)