# Trying to get two path variables into spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, path-variables

I am trying to get multiple path variables into a spring mvc controller but I am getting the following error

**Error:**

```
          SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [stp] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments to which they apply: public java.lang.String edu.bnu.fyp.stp.web.controller.WatchlistController.saveWatchlist java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)] with root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException: An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments to which they apply: public java.lang.String edu.bnu.fyp.stp.web.controller.WatchlistController.saveWatchlit(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
```

Here is what I am trying to do

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{tutorId}/{studentId}" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String saveWatchlist(@PathVariable(value = "tutorId") String tutorId, @PathVariable(value = "studentId") String studentId , BindingResult bindingResult, ModelAttribute model, HttpSession session) {

    System.out.println("Tutor ID is: " + tutorId);
    System.out.println("Student ID is: " + studentId);

    return "StudentWatchlist";
}
```

**JSP:**

```
 <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/watchlist/add/${tutorList.userId}/${sessionScope.user.userId}"> Add </a>
```

**Note:**

This URL is working and in JSP you can actually see the URL calling the controller with both IDs in the link. But for some reason, I am not able to catch these values in the controller. I have also tried the RequestParm solution, it didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried to set bindingResult after model attribute?

Comment: @Vadeg Yes I tried that, same results

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18646314/430426

Answer (score 0):

Remove `BindingResult` and `ModelAttribute` if you have no plans to use them in the code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{tutorId}/{studentId}" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String saveWatchlist(@PathVariable(value = "tutorId") String tutorId, @PathVariable(value = "studentId") String studentId, HttpSession session) {

    System.out.println("Tutor ID is: " + tutorId);
    System.out.println("Student ID is: " + studentId);

    return "StudentWatchlist";
}
```

Comment: I do need to use them, this is just a short version of the controller function.

Answer (score 0):

You can return ModelAndView() instead of returning a String.

For passing multiple value to jsp as view use any model class and store the values recieved into object and return the ModelAndView with view (*i.e welcome.jsp*), model (*i.e Student*) and value (*i.e object of Student class with value*).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{tutorId}/{studentId}", method = 
RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView saveWatchlist(@PathVariable(value = "tutorId") String tutorId, 
@PathVariable(value = "studentId") String studentId) {

    //console output   
    System.out.println("Tutor ID is: " + tutorId);
    System.out.println("Student ID is: " + studentId);

    //bind the recieved value into a object
    Student st = new Student();
    st.setStudentId(studentId);
    st.setTutorId(tutorId);

    return new ModelAndView("welcome","student",st);
}
```

> Student.java

```
public class Student {
    private String studentId,tutorId;
    //there getter and setter goes here

}
```

> welcome.jsp

```
Student Id: ${student.getStudentId()}
Tutor Id: ${student.getTutorId()}
```